# Getting the list of all the registered geofences

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, geofencing, android-geofence

I am developing an android application that uses Geofences. I want to get the list of all the geofences which are currently in the registered state and which were registered by my app. Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Will suggest you persist your geofences in order so that you can retrieve them from a local database. The geofences won't be persisted by default so if you reboot you need to re-add them, so the best way is having them stored on a local database or any other persistent storage.

Comment: I have stored the place Ids in an SQLite database. But I need to re register them as and when the geofences get expired. Is there any callback as such or any way in which I can achieve the task of re-registering them with the play services as soon as they get expired. I don't want to use NEVER_EXPIRE. Please help.